# Undefined reference error while using custom system call in kernel 3.19

Tags: kernel, c

I'm trying to import new system call in the kernel 3.19. I've followed the tutorial given [here](https://tssurya.wordpress.com/2014/08/19/adding-a-hello-world-system-call-to-linux-kernel-3-16-0/)!

This is my simple code to implement factorial calculation via system call.

```
 #include <linux/kernel.h>


 asmlinkage long sys_fact(int a)
 {
    int n;
    int c;
    for(n = 1;n <= a;n++)
    c = c * n;  
    printk(KERN_INFO "Factorial calculated!\n");


    return((long) c);
 }
```

I'm getting Undefined reference to sys_fact error when I try to compile the C code.
The program in which I'm using this system call is as follows.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
  int n;
  printf("Enter a number to calculate it's factorial\n");
  scanf("%d", &n);
  printf("Factorial of %d = %d\n", n, sys_fact(9));

  return 0;
}
```

Output when tried to compile above code using **gcc -v -c fact.c**

```
    Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.8/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,java,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.8 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.8 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-libmudflap --enable-plugin --with-system-zlib --disable-browser-plugin --enable-java-awt=gtk --enable-gtk-cairo --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-amd64/jre --enable-java-home --with-jvm-root-dir=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-amd64 --with-jvm-jar-dir=/usr/lib/jvm-exports/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-amd64 --with-arch-directory=amd64 --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --enable-objc-gc --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.8.2 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-c' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/cc1 -quiet -v -imultiarch x86_64-linux-gnu fact.c -quiet -dumpbase fact.c -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -auxbase fact -version -fstack-protector -Wformat -Wformat-security -o /tmp/ccbquF56.s
GNU C (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) version 4.8.2 (x86_64-linux-gnu)
    compiled by GNU C version 4.8.2, GMP version 5.1.3, MPFR version 3.1.2-p3, MPC version 1.0.1
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/local/include/x86_64-linux-gnu"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/include-fixed
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
 /usr/include
End of search list.
GNU C (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) version 4.8.2 (x86_64-linux-gnu)
    compiled by GNU C version 4.8.2, GMP version 5.1.3, MPFR version 3.1.2-p3, MPC version 1.0.1
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
Compiler executable checksum: dc75e0628c9356affcec059d0c81cc01
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-c' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 as -v --64 -o fact.o /tmp/ccbquF56.s
GNU assembler version 2.24 (x86_64-linux-gnu) using BFD version (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.24
COMPILER_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/
LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../lib/:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../:/lib/:/usr/lib/
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-c' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
```

My system is 64 bit ubuntu 14.04 and I've followed above mentioned tutorial according to my system.

Also, I've combined following commands while installing kernel, and I think this is the reason it did not gave error while installation of kernel.

```
 make && make modules_install && make install
```

Kernel installation took 2-3 hours, and I'm frustrated now.
Please help!!

Comment: @anx kernel is installed successfully. I'm using it now.

Comment: @anx Have a look.

Comment: @anx I'd edited wrong output of compiler by mistake, sorry. Now it is OK.

Comment: How are you linking the code?

Comment: @anx I'm not getting what you are saying, sorry.

Comment: the variable 'c' is not initialized, so the result of the calculation: c =c*a; could be anything.  suggest initialize 'c', to 1

Comment: user input is never to be trusted, so the code should be checking that the input parameter is >0 and less than the max factorial that can be generated in the range 1...2gig.

Comment: after the first complete compile, subsequent compiles (via a makefile and the make utility) will be MUCH faster as only the changed modules need to be recompiled.

Comment: regarding this line: 'make && make modules_install && make install'  usually the first step is './configure' after running the config utility to set up all the variable info for the kernel.  Note: the config utility should only need to be run once, rather than once for each compile/link

Comment: @user3629249 even though there is bug in my factorial code, it will compile, which means sys_fact() should be defined. Also, I can see fact.o(object file) in kernel source.